# Probability distribution of random products of elements of a generating set of a finite non-abelian group

Tags: gr.group-theory, pr.probability, finite-groups, probability-distributions

Let $G$ be a finite non-abelian group, and consider a choice of $N$ distinct elements $g_{0},g_{1},\ldots,g_{N-1}\in G$ that generate $G$. Now, let $t$ be an arbitrary positive integer, and let $d_{1},\ldots,d_{K}\in\left\{ 0,\ldots,N-1\right\}$  be the $N$-ary digits of $t$, so that:$$t=\sum_{k=1}^{K}d_{k}N^{k-1}$$ is then the $N$-ary/$N$-adic representation of $t$. Next, letting $\mathbb{N}_{1}$ denote the positive integers, define the map $\chi:\mathbb{N}_{1}\rightarrow G$ by: $$\chi\left(\sum_{k=1}^{K}d_{k}N^{k-1}\right)=\prod_{k=1}^{K}g_{d_{k}}=g_{d_{1}}g_{d_{2}}\cdots g_{d_{K}}$$ Finally, make $\mathbb{N}_{1}$ into a probability space by equipping it with the probability measure defined by the upper density of a set of integers: $$\textrm{P}\left(A\right)=\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\left|A\cap\left\{ 1,2,\ldots,n\right\} \right|}{n},\textrm{ }\forall A\subseteq\mathbb{N}_{1}$$

With this set-up, we can then think of $\chi$ as a random variable on $\mathbb{N}_{1}$. That being so, is it then true that $\chi$ will be uniformly distributed?—i.e.: $$\textrm{P}\left(\chi=g\right)\overset{?}{=}\frac{1}{\left|G\right|},\textrm{ }\forall g\in G$$

My intuition has convinced me that this must be the case whenever $G$ is *abelian*, however, I cannot help but feel that in the non-abelian case, the probability distribution of $\chi$ somehow depends on the particular choice of the generating set $\left\{ g_{0},\ldots,g_{N-1}\right\}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To begin with, endowing the set of integers with the upper density is quite far from making it a probability space. Nonetheless, the question you ask still makes sense. Namely, you consider the $G$-valued sequence defined by your function $\chi$ and just ask whether the empirical frequencies of its values converge to the uniform distribution.

The answer is indeed "yes". The proof consists of 3 steps.

(1) Take $n=N^d$ to be the $d$-th power of $N$. Then the empirical distribution at time $n$ is just the $d$-fold convolution of the uniform measure on your generating set, which is well-known to converge to the uniform distribution on $G$.

(2) The uniform distribution on $G$ is preserved under the multiplication by any group element, which implies that for any $N$-rational numbers $0\le \alpha<\beta\le 1$ the empirical frequencies over the sequence of intervals 
$[N^d\alpha, N^d\beta]$ converge to the uniform distribution as well.

(3) It remains to deduce the claim from (2).

Comment: "To begin with, endowing the set of integers with the upper density is quite far from making it a probability space" — As I'm not quite good in probability, would you mind explaining why? Since the upper density is defined for all infinite sets of positive integers, doesn't that make the set of "measurable" sets into a sigma algebra?

Comment: The point here is $\sigma$-additivity (rather than just the presence of a $\sigma$-algebra). The "measure" you are defining is not only not $\sigma$-additive (look at the partition of the integers into one-point sets), but is not even finitely additive (it is possible that both a subset of integers and its complement simultaneously have upper density 1).

Comment: What about if we instead look at natural density (where both upper and lower density exist and are the same)?

Comment: In this case you obtain a **finitely additive** measure on the algebra (not $\sigma$-algebra!) of subsets which have a density. By using the Hahn-Banach theorem you can extend it to a finitely additive measure on all subsets of $\mathbb N$. However, this is not of much use as finitely additive measures are quite different from the "usual" $\sigma$-additive ones and are not really used in the probability theory.